# How to allow specific IPs though the firewall?

Tags: apache, ip, localhost, firewall, vpn

I have a local Apache server and I want it to be accessible from other machine. I found out that it's possible after turning off (the external, Windows based) firewall.

Can I make it accessible from a specific IP without turning the firewall off?

Comment: By "the firewall" are you meaning IPCHAINS/IPTABLES (or some other software firewall) running on the server, or an external firewall, possibly at your router?

Comment: Ta.... but sorry, which application. Usually windows apps are straightforward to GUI config (once you suss the menus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to *Windows Firewall* GUI and add an exception from the *Exceptions Tab*..while adding the exception you can change it's scope and can provide a specific IP under *Custom List*..

Do ensure that the *Don't allow exceptions checkbox* on the *General Tab* under the *Windows Firewall* GUI is Unchecked..

Voilà your Apache server is now accessible from a specific IP without turning the firewall off..!!

Comment: can i do that from windows server 2008?

Comment: you may go through [this article](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/configure-Windows-Server-2008-advanced-firewall-MMC-snap-in.html) on how you can configure Windows Firewall under windows server 2008