# Access my localhost from my Android tablet

Tags: android, networking, config

I'm running Apache/MySQL/PHP and I want to view my localhost on my android tablet. I've read in here that if the tablet is also in the same WiFi network that the server on my laptop, I could find out what the ip address of my laptop is with the ipconfig command and make it work...

So the IP is

```
192.168.0.199
```

I went to my tablet, entered the IP and nothing. Kept researching in here and found out what the problem was: My windows firewall!!!

If I disable the windows firewall, I can access my localhost from my tablet. Obviously, i don't want to disable my firewall, so the question is how do I allow my windows firewall to give access to my android tablet?

I figure that I need to add an exception, but i have no idea what the parameters are.
Help!

Comment: Without list of ports you are trying to access no one can answer your question, but on other hand when you have list of ports you know the answer... So I guess the real question should be "how to figure out what ports need to be open for accessing XXXX" (I really hop you know what you are trying to access...)

Comment: So i do i foind out what port i need to open

Comment: You need to know what are you trying to access - default ports are easy like web server 80/443 (http/https), SMTP 25,... MySQL should have documentation what ports need to be open for remote access, similar for all other servers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can allow your device to access your localhost without disabling the firewall by following the steps:

1- get know your mobile IP address, it differs how to get it from android device to device, In my device, I can have it by going through settings -> WIFI -> advanced then search for my mobile IP address.

2- follow the right answer of the is [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179799/how-to-allow-specific-ips-though-the-firewall) to  make your firewall allow access of specific IP address.

but as @Alexei said.. you should know the port you want to access otherwise you will end up accessing nothing.

hope this is useful for you

Comment: ok, i kept researching and this post (http://superuser.com/questions/92488/apache-server-on-windows-7-opening-up-ports) help me... i've opened port 80 and that work... looks like Windows 7 Firewall has a fear of the 80 port...